# Insert data when the key match using Google API Client

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I want to insert  `uri` when `number` is matched in A column and put uri into the last colunmn of row which number is matched. I using `spreadsheet.values().get()` & `spreadsheet.values().update()`, but I don't know how to check the data of column A and insert data after I found which is what It need.

The data of A column is like,"YVA00001", "YVA00002"... .

```html
import json
from re import A
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
import pandas as pd
from main import GoogleAPIClient


app = flask.Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


class GoogleSheets(GoogleAPIClient):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # 呼叫 GoogleAPIClient.__init__()，並提供 serviceName, version, scope
        super().__init__(
            'sheets',
            'v4',
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
        )

    def appendWorksheet(self, spreadsheetId: str, range: str, uri: json, number: json):
        result = self.googleAPIService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId, range = range).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])

        column_len = len(values[0])
        
        for i in values[0]:
            if number in values[0][i]:
                break
    
        response = self.googleAPIService.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId,
            range= f"工作表1!{chr(65+column_len)}1",
            valueInputOption="RAW",
            body= {'values': [[uri]]},
            ).execute()
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

If I understand you correctly, you want to add `uri` to the last column in each row where column A value is equal to `number`.

Assuming that the above is correct, and that all rows have the same amount of columns, there are several problems here:

- When using `for i in values[0]` the `i` is each element in `values[0]` it is not an index, so it shouldn't be used as such.
- You are not checking which rows have value `number` in column A.
- The range you provided is only the first row in the last column. Assuming that you want to insert `uri` value to potentially several rows, and not just the first one, you'll have to modify the provided `range` when updating the values.

#### Solution:

With that said, I'd suggest the following workflow:

- Iterate through `values`, not `values[0]`.
- Create a new list (`newData` in the sample below) where the new data in last column will be appended.
- For each element in `values`, check whether `values[i][0]` (corresponding to column A) equals `number`.
- If it equals number append `uri` to `newData`. If it doesn't append the current value from last column to `newData`.
- Update the sheet values with `newData`.

#### Code sample:

```
def appendWorksheet(self, spreadsheetId: str, range: str, uri: json, number: json):
    result = self.googleAPIService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId, range = range).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    column_len = len(values[0])
    newData = []
    for row in values:
        if row[0] == number:
            newData.append([uri])
        else:
            newData.append([row[column_len-1]])


    response = self.googleAPIService.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId,
        range= f"工作表1!{chr(64+column_len)}1:{chr(64+column_len)}{len(newData)}",
        valueInputOption="RAW",
        body= {'values': newData},
        ).execute()
```

#### Note:

I don't know what kind of values are `uri` and `number` but I assumed they are strings. If that's not the case, the sample above might not work as intended.

Comment: `newData.append([row[column_len-1]])` will cause an error message that shows
`IndexError: list index out of range` . Is it a necessary code？
* uri is a base64 string & number is a string too and I let them transform as JSON type

Comment: @Jayco Yes, it is a necessary code. If you encountered this error, it means not all rows in your sheet have the same length. That was one of my assumptions when I posted my answer, as mentioned on top (`that all rows have the same amount of columns`). In that case, consider providing a copy of your spreadsheet, showing your data structure, in order to look into this in more detail.

Comment: `number` will be like "YVS202200001, YVS202200002 ..." in each row of "A", and the `uri `is the base64 code ,data URI,like "data:image/png;base64,....." int each rows of last column "P". The question is that I want to push `uri` into the correct row which number sent from python can match number in google sheet.(Sorry, my english skill doesn't well)

Comment: If today I have 5 data, YVS202200001~YVS202200005, and I need to push `uri `which number is  `YVS202200002`.(the data in google sheet is Decreasing sort).
Then the `uri` should show in "P5" which "A5" is `YVS202200002` in google sheet

Comment: @Jayco Yes, I understand what you want to do, and it's exactly what the suggested script is doing when I test this. Since it's not working for you though, it would be useful to have access to a copy of your spreadsheet, so I can see why it's not working for you. It's hard to investigate with the provided information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. I use for loop to check the data in values[][],and
let `count` the store the length of data. So when the for loop break It can update data into which it should be inserted in.

Thanks for everyone who answered my problem.

```js
    def appendWorksheet(self, spreadsheetId: str, rang: str, uri: json, num: str):
        #獲取google sheet當前資料
        result = self.googleAPIService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId, range = rang).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])

        column_len = len(values[0])
        newData = []
        count = 1
        #檢查是否有獲取表格資料 print(values[0][0])

        #檢查每一筆資料單據是否有符合當前上傳資料附贈之單據
        for i in range(len(values)):
            #檢查是否有成功獲取表單資料 print(values[i][0])
            if values[i][0] == num:
                newData.append(1)
                count = count + 1
                break
            else:
                newData.append(0)
                count = count + 1

        #將資料上傳到上面迴圈檢查後確認的欄位
        response = self.googleAPIService.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId,
            range= f"表單回應 1!{chr(64+17)}{count-1}",
            valueInputOption="RAW",
            body= {'values': [[uri]]},
            ).execute()
        return "upload success"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).